# The file is not associated with any file type.Please define the association

Tags: android

I have an audio file with extension .mp3, I wanted to add it to "raw" folder in Android studio, in order to access it from my java file like:

```
Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayAudio.class);
```

I see question mark on my audio file in raw folder and whenever I click on it, it shows me a screen with this message:

> The file 'xy.mp3' is not associated with any file type.Please define the association

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

I had this too the other day, trying to find out which file type can be associated. 
Then I just realized that the file name of your .mp3 should be all lowercase. AS cannot recognize files with uppercase letters in file name, I changed it, and it runs just fine. Not sure if that's your case too.

Comment: Isn't it clear from OP's messages that "mp3" was lowercase?

Answer (score 4):

The window that appears there asking for the type is just that Android studio doesn't know to open the file so you can visualize/listen to the file. It does not affect how the file is handled by android at all.

Since Android Studio does not have a media player, I suggest you to select Open matching files in associated application That will launch your default music player and play that mp3.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that, I was dragging .mp3 file into raw folder in Android Studio, as I was doing it in Eclips, but in Eclips I hadn't encountered such issue. So what I did was:

I opened my project folder:

**C:\Users\xyx\AndroidStudioProjects\PlayAudio\app\src\main\res\raw**

and past my .mp3 file in raw folder, and now I don't see any question mark on my audio file in raw folder

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that android studio doesn't know what this file is (understandably enough, as it doesn't contain a music player/editor). You should still be able to access this file as any raw resource.

Comment: yes i can access this but I can't run my app it shows me the 
The file 'xy.mp3' is not associated with any file type.Please define the association

Answer (score 0):

You can also just hit "Cancel" on that window that pops up and the file is still there.